# A trigger to calculate and print the difference between old and new salary when the salary is updated

Tags: mysql, triggers

Employee table is defined as Employee(eno, ename, salary).

Write a trigger to calculate and print the difference between old and new salary when the salary is updated.

I tried the following trigger. It seems to calculate the difference. How to print it?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER t1
AFTER UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
    DECLARE sal_diff DECIMAL(10,2);
    IF eno = new.eno THEN
        IF (new.salary < old.salary) THEN
            SET sal_diff = old.salary - new.salary;
        ELSE
            SET sal_diff = new.salary - old.salary;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the syntax error you get, that will help us, help you.

Comment: Print is not a mysql verb.

Comment: I get the same error even without the print statement.

Comment: You need to use SET a = b - c (and read the manual)

Comment: Thank you! My bad.

Comment: A trigger isn't the place to do this in my view. Somewhere in your db you should have an employee history table and you should be able to check if there is a change in salary between the most recent history record and the current employee record. You could use a trigger to capture the fact that something has changed into a change fact table son that you know you need to carry out a history comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER t1
AFTER UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
    DECLARE sal_diff DECIMAL(10,2);
    IF new.salary < old.salary THEN
       set @sal_diff = old.salary - new.salary;
    ELSE
       set @sal_diff = new.salary - old.salary;
    END IF;
   -- Use  @sal_diff where you want it;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger